# Comment "no longer needed" flag declined, but comment removed anyway?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, comment-flags

Yesterday, I flagged a comment that was no longer needed on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4236294/11942268). It was usefull some years ago, but has been merged into the answer, thus being not helpful anymore and wasting everyones time reading it (ok, at least mine).

My flag was declined, but the comment was removed anyway. It looks like a mod added credits for the comment that has already been merged into the answer and may be deleted it then.

I would be ok, if such a flag gets declined and the comment stays. But if it gets deleted, then the flag was helpful imo.

In my opinion, it is like improving an edit request (me being the editor, mod the reviewer). The editor does not get "punished" in this situation.

Can someone enlighten me on how to understand that? Or should that be corrected?

Comment: Bear in mind mods have _no_ context (IIRC) when reviewing comment flags. They see the comment, and nothing else. It could have simply been a mistake in reviewing, after all mistakes happen. A single declined flag is nothing to get upset over.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I declined your flag.

A No Longer Needed (NLN) flag should be used when there is no longer a use for the comment and it can be *immediately* deleted. That was not the case here. The code from the comment had been copied into the answer (with the deletion of one character and added formatting), but attribution to the original author had not been provided in the answer, or even the edit summary. The CC BY-SA license under which *all* user content is contributed to Stack Exchange requires attribution when copying the content, even when that content is in a comment.

If the comment had been immediately deleted, which is what you were requesting with an NLN flag, then there would have been no indication at all as to where the code came from. Thus, the comment was still needed. Because the comment was still required, I declined your flag.

If you wanted the comment deleted (i.e. the NLN flag to be helpful), then you needed to have eliminated all need for the comment, including the need for the comment to remain in order to indicate the source of the code. In other words, you should have edited the answer to include attribution for the copied content. If you had done that prior to flagging as NLN, then I would have just deleted the comment, marking your flag as helpful. Editing the post to include attribution is something which any user, particularly a user with full editing privileges, could, and should, do. Editing in that attribution is not a function which requires a moderator, nor is it something which is a normal part of a moderator handling an NLN flag (i.e. an NLN flag means "this comment can be immediately deleted").

Given that I was already viewing the answer and attribution was needed, I edited the answer to add attribution. Once attribution was added, the comment was no longer needed, so I deleted the comment.

Unfortunately, comment flags can only be declined or marked helpful. There is no ability for moderators to dispute them, nor to provide explanatory text when declining them or marking them helpful. Moderators cannot mark a comment flag as helpful without deleting or editing the comment. So, unfortunately, there was no way to give you an explanation along with disposing of the flag.

[Note: Yes, the person who originally copied the code from the comment into the answer should have provided attribution. Unfortunately, they did not provide attribution in either the answer or edit summary. However, the fact that they should have done so doesn't change the state of the answer and comment at the time you raised the NLN flag.]

Comment: This is not the answer I was expecting, but I like that attribution requirements are being enforced

Comment: Out of curiosity: why did you add a link to the comment to your edit when you were already deleting it? AFAIK not even users with 10K+ would be able to see it.

Comment: @BillTür I added the link to the comment because having a link (actually, including the URI) to the original content is one of the requirements of the CC BY-SA license. In version 3.0, it's required in [CC BY-SA 3.0 § 4(c)(iii)](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/legalcode), which is [the version I'm most familiar with](/a/356304/3773011). That I was planning to delete the comment doesn't change that requirement. Having the link to the comment also allows a moderator to know where to find the comment, if that's ever needed (unlikely).

Comment: @Thomas If comment flags allowed moderators to dispute them, I would have done so, particularly if I could attach an explanation along with the dispute. There's no option to do that with comment flags. The only flag types which moderators can dispute are spam and rude/abusive (including an explanation with a disputed spam/R/A flag is possible, but a bit convoluted). Ultimately, it came down to: Do I want you to use NLN flags in exactly that manner again? The answer was no, I want/need you to do something different. Comment flags give no way to communicate that, other than by declining them.

Comment: @Makyen Perhaps what Thomas is wondering is why you didn't make the edit *first*, and then delete the comment, thus marking the flag as helpful. I'm assuming you were only viewing the answer and comment because it was flagged (you didn't come across it organically). You mentioned in your answer not being able to give Thomas an explanation along with disposing of the flag; did you intend to reach out to him to give him an explanation anyway, for example if he had not asked this Meta question?