# Should there be a mechanism in place to make users answer as answers instead of comments?

Tags: discussion, answers

This has been a personal pet peeve of mine lately, (and I see it a *lot*), because, as I frequently go through the newest questions/top questions/tagged questions lists, these answered questions aren't marked as answered at all, let alone as having an "accepted answer".

So the end result is we waste our time clicking into all of these answered questions, and only find out that they're already answered by having to read the list of comments.

It also makes it more difficult than it should be to actually find a working answer when you're searching for one, when it doesn't show an accepted answer.

I don't know off the top of my head how the right way to solve this would be, but it seems there should be *some* mechanism to stop this behavior from happening.

Anyone else agree? (or disagree?)

[image]

Comment: "but it seems there should be some mechanism to stop this behavior from happening." -- why? Doesn't hurt anyone, and it's extremely useful to [leave comments in some cases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/4218/332043). Also, some chains of comments some times accidentally results in an answer - a proper answer can rather be written later (instead of some system to prevent it), or as the question Jeanne Dark linked points out, you can copy-paste it as a community wiki answer with attribution if you absolutely feel that comment is answer material

Comment: Also, that comment was left extremely recently. You can ask them to move it to an answer, but there's also a real chance they haven't seen the comment saying their comment worked.

Comment: @Zoe "why? Doesn't hurt anyone". I thought I already explained what it "hurts" in my post? ;) After viewing Jeanne Dark's link, I think the number of upvotes to the asker's question shows some agreement.

Comment: @Zoe "You can ask them to move it to an answer". The screenshot also shows that I did that already. ;) But, I don't feel like the onus should be placed on other answerers to "hound" the ones who do this.

Comment: @JeanneDark Thanks, that did answer my question, though it's a bit sad that the question was placed years ago and still no better mechanism has been put in place other than copy/pasting the answer, and marking it as a Wiki. Seems a bit too "janitorial-like" for answers to have to follow around other answerers with a proverbial mop and bucket. Especially when done (frequently) by answerers with 10's and even 100's of thousands in rep.

Comment: Probably there ought to be a way to expedite marking that question as a duplicate - I find it difficult to believe it hasn't been asked before.  More seriously, I will sometimes "answer in the comments" if a question is a typo (and vtc) or is trivial and likely to have been answered many times before but unlikely to have a decent duplicate target.

Comment: I'm not a subject matter expert in those tags but am betting there is/are duplicate(s) for that question. Often leaving a comment answer is simpler than using the horrible site search to find those dups. Better site search would help a lot

Comment: Related: [Answerers who only use comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253045/11682469)

Comment: There is the mechanism that comments do not accrue reputation.

Comment: Re *"...go through the newest questions/top questions/tagged questions lists, these answered questions aren't marked as answered at all"*: The official term is "accepted" (this could be read as if there wasn't any information about whether answered or not).

Comment: Or what do you mean? That you waste your time opening questions with formally no answers, but actually ***answered in comments***? To the left, e.g. on *[All Questions, tab "Newest"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?tab=Newest)*, is the number of answers. E.g., "0 answers" and "2 answers".

Comment: Re *"clicking into all of these answered questions"*: Don't you mean *"clicking into all of these* ***unanswered*** *questions"* (the opposite, at least formally)? - where the questions are answered in comments.

Comment: I sometimes point out something in a comment and I'm told that it should be an answer when I know I don't have enough for a decent answer. I don't think I'll find a better example than what happened recently: I commented something and a user posted an answer that contained the same thing with a bit more details. I was told my comment should be an answer and the existing answer should have been a comment. So, paradoxically I somehow managed to answer the question as a comment but that information shouldn't be a full answer. [The same user said both things](https://i.imgur.com/8crtzCX.png).

Comment: @vlaz i have no problem with that, i sometimes do that as well. The problem is when that ends up being the solution and the asker thanks you for it, and then you don't take that original comment and add it as the answer.

Comment: @Peter Mortensen "Re *"...go through the newest questions/top questions/tagged questions lists, these answered questions aren't marked as answered at all"*: The official term is "accepted" (this could be read as if there wasn't any information about whether answered or not)." No, i said exactly what i meant; when there are NO answers at all, accepted or otherwise, but there are comments with the working solution in it, then the questions list shows NO activity. Which means answerers like myself end up clicking into them and having to extrapolate from the comments whether or was answered or not

Comment: @Peter Mortensen "Re *"clicking into all of these answered questions"*: Don't you mean *"clicking into all of these* ***unanswered*** *questions"* (the opposite, at least formally)? - where the questions are answered in comments." Again no, i said exactly what i meant... When there's an ANSWER (accepted and working) in the comment. Therefore "answered questions".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can copy the comment's solution into a community-wiki answer. Remember to add attribution! This preserves the question-answer format.

Then, flag the original comment for moderator intervention and explain why it's no longer needed.

I think it's the best approach to save questions and answers.

Comment: Don't you also need to link to the comment? I mean doesn't the requirement say that one needs to link to the original content?

Comment: @Scratte See [Makyen's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/400898/11682469): "If you wanted the comment deleted (i.e. the NLN flag to be helpful), then you needed to have eliminated all need for the comment, including the need for the comment to remain in order to indicate the source of the code. In other words, you should have edited the answer to include attribution for the copied content."

Comment: @JeanneDark There's no mentioning of providing a link to a comment in that Answer anywhere. I don't see the relevance at all. I'm referring to "Provide a link to the original page or answer" in the [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Not whether or not attribution is needed or if it's required before or after a flag on the comment.

Comment: @Scratte So let's apply what is written there to this specific case rather than follow it to the letter. The text is pretty specific about linking to text which exists "somewhere else" - a different site or maybe a different answer. It does not specifically mention comments which happen to live in the same page, and since comments in this site are treated as second class citizens all that would make me not feel bad about assuming we don't need to waste so many words on it. Just do it.

Comment: @Gimby I do not like if when someone adds half attribution saying a user said something somewhere. I prefer having a link and specifying was was said comes from a comment and exactly what post the comment was posted on, which you get a from a link to the comment. Saying "Just do it" means that people can just do whatever they want in whatever way they interpret the rules, if they even read them at all. "Lets apply what was written there" is exactly my point. It doesn't say.

Comment: @Scratte but then you'd end up with a dead link, because the comment has served it's purpose and can easily be removed. It doesn't make sense to apply that specific bullet point of the guidelines strictly to comments. But it does to apply the remaining two bullet points.

Comment: @Gimby I don't understand how that matters. That's the same as linking to an accepted Answer. Even if it goes dead, anyone above 10K can see from where it came. If you link to a comment, you'll land on the post even if the comment is deleted. And moderators can always see the deleted comment.